# How do I cause a macro to run immediately after a textbox is populated in my userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a userform that will filter a table immediately after a single text box is populated with the filter criteria.

The filter criteria is in a single text box (the only place to input data in this userform).

I am using a barcode scanner to populate the textbox and this criteria will then be used to filter the data in my table.

I would like the data to be filtered immediately after the textbox is populated from the barcode scanner (without having to press a command button to filter the data).

I am pretty new to programming in general, any ideas? Thanks!

I have created a userform that will filter that data, but only after I press a command button to filter it. I would like this to happen automatically after the barcode scanner inputs the data.

UPDATE I have moved the code to the sub below and gotten rid of the command button. Now I would like to be able to hide the userform automatically after the data is filtered. When I add the Userform1.Hide, all the filters are removed from my table, but when I comment this line out, it works fine (but the userform remains unhidden). Any ideas?

> Option Explicit    Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
>
> ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, 
>    Criteria1:=TextBox1.Value
>
> Userform1.Hide
>
> End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Private Sub TextBox1_Change()` routine is called whevever a change is made to `TextBox1`, that is, for every character that is entered. So, put your code there. At each call, check that the textbox has received a complete and valid filter. If not, just return. Otherwise, run the filter (and clear the textbox to be able to receive another filter).

Comment: That was a good idea putting the code in the Private Sub TextBox1_Change() routine, it allowed me to get rid of the command button altogether.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "At each call, check that the textbox has received a complete and valid filter"? I understand the premise, but I am unsure of how to put it in VBA language.     Also, I would like the userform to be hidden automatically after the data is input and the filter is complete. I put Userform1.Hide in a line underneath the filter line, but because the textbox clears at this time, all filters are removed from the table. Is there a way around this?    Thanks for your help!

Comment: The textbox shouldn't "clear" on the `UserForm.Hide`, unless you're doing something elsewhere in your code to cause the textbox to clear or otherwise unloading the form.

Comment: That seems like it should be the case. I updated the question above with the new code. It works fine when the Userform1.Hide line is commented out, but when it isn't, I have that same problem.